# Why is my binding in constructor not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bind

In my react native app I have a function for when the user presses a button (handleButtonAPressed) which uses setState, so I am trying to bind it in my constructor with the following code

```
const handleButtonAPressed = () => {
  this.setState({x: this.state.x + 1});
}

export default class SvgExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    this.handleButtonAPressed = this.handleButtonAPressed.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <RoundButton onPress={handleButtonAPressed} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

However, I am getting the error:

**'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.handleButtonAPressed.bind)**

Comment: You probably have a callback somewhere that has `function() { this.handleButtonAPressed()}` somewhere, so that the `this` context is lost before you get to calling the function you intend, you should put in your code how you actually call the function in the end

Comment: Please show the full component

Comment: @Vencovsky I have updated the description with the full component.

Comment: why are you using bind instead of `onPress={ evt => this.handleButtonPressed() }`? Your constructor should not be responsible for rebinding class functions as instance functions. That's just baking in an extra layer of bug surface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`handleButtonAPressed` should be inside your class so you can do `this.handleButtonAPressed.bind(this)`. If you don't have `handleButtonAPressed` inside you class, `this.handleButtonAPressed` will be `undefined` and impossible to do `.bind`.

Here is what you should do

```
export default class SvgExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    this.handleButtonAPressed = this.handleButtonAPressed.bind(this);
  }

  handleButtonAPressed() {
    this.setState({x: this.state.x + 1});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <RoundButton onPress={handleButtonAPressed} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```